# Let $f(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+5$ where $x\in[-6,6]$. If the range of the function is [a,b] where $a,b\in N$, then find the value of (a+b)

Tags: functions, inequality, quadratics, maxima-minima

Let $f(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)+5$ where $x\in[-6,6]$. If the range of the function is [a,b] where $a,b\in N$, then find the value of (a+b)

My attempt is as follows:-

Rewrite $f(x)=g(x)+5$ where $g(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)$

Let's find the maximum value of g(x)

It can be clearly seen that from $x=-6$ to $x=6$, maximum value of $g(x)$ is at $x=6$.

$$g(6)=5040$$

Let's find the minimum value of $g(x)$

From the sign scheme one can see that negative value of $g(x)$ occurs in the interval $(-4,-3)$ and $(-2,-1)$

Hence intuitively it feels that the minimum value of g(x) would be at $x=-\dfrac{3}{2}$ or at $x=-\dfrac{7}{2}$ as in case of parabola also, minimum value is at average of both the roots.

So $g\left(-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)=-\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{3}{2}\cdot\dfrac{5}{2}=-\dfrac{15}{8}$

At $x=-\dfrac{7}{2}$, $g\left(-\dfrac{7}{2}\right)=-\dfrac{5}{2}\cdot\dfrac{3}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}=-\dfrac{15}{8}$

So range of $g(x)$ would be $[\dfrac{-15}{8},5040]$

Hence range of $f(x)$=$\left[\dfrac{25}{8},5045\right]$

But it is given that the range is $[a,b]$ where $a,b\in N$

I am stuck here.  I am also not able to prove mathematically that at $x=-\dfrac{3}{2}$ or $x=-\dfrac{7}{2}$, minimum value of $g(x)$ will occur.

Please help me in this.

Comment: "Hence intuitively it feels that the minimum value of g(x) would be at x=−3/2 or at x=−7/2 as in case of parabola also, minimum value is at average of both the roots."

While this may apply for quadratic functions, it does not apply for quartic functions.  You would need calculus to determine the min/max values.

Comment: yah, but then what is the other way to find minimum value?

Comment: Are you allowed to use techniques in calculus? i.e. do you know what differentiation is?

Comment: You can try to use First Derivative Test. Check for all points $x$ such that $f’(x)=0$, as well as the 2 end-points $x=-6,6$, then compare all values of $f(x)$ at those points. I think this problem is extremely difficult “intuitively”. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test

Comment: $f'(x)=0$, $2x^3+15x^2+35x+25=0$, I am getting no trivial roots here

Answer (score 2):

Like you have suggested, consider the function $$g(x)=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4).$$

$g'(x)$ potentially has minimum values at its critical numbers, which we can find by setting the derivative equal to $0$.
\begin{align}
g(x)&=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)\\
\log g(x)&=\log\big((x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)\big)\\
\log g(x)&=\log(x+1)+\log(x+2)+\log(x+3)+\log(x+4)\\
\frac{d}{dx}\big(\log g(x)\big)&=\frac{d}{dx}\big(\log(x+1)+\log(x+2)+\log(x+3)+\log(x+4)\big)\\
\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}&=\frac1{x+1}+\frac1{x+2}+\frac1{x+3}+\frac1{x+4}\\
g'(x)&=g(x)\bigg(\frac1{x+1}+\frac1{x+2}+\frac1{x+3}+\frac1{x+4}\bigg)\\
g'(x)&=(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)\bigg(\frac1{x+1}+\frac1{x+2}+\frac1{x+3}+\frac1{x+4}\bigg)
\end{align}

Solving the equation $$\frac1{x+1}+\frac1{x+2}+\frac1{x+3}+\frac1{x+4}=0$$ gives us $x=-\dfrac52-\dfrac{\sqrt5}2$, $-\dfrac52$, and $-\dfrac52+\dfrac{\sqrt5}2$.  To find maximum and minimum values on an interval, we then need to compare the values at these critical numbers and at the bounds of the interval.

The maximum value is $g(6)=5040$ (as you found) and the minimum value is $g(-\frac52+\frac{\sqrt5}2)=-1$.

Since $f(x)=g(x)+5$, the range of $f(x)$ on $[-6,6]$ is therefore $[-1+5,5040+5]$ or $\boxed{[4,5045]}.$  As a result, the value of $a+b$ is $\boxed{5049}$.

Comment: As a note:  I have left out the _trivial_ aspects of the solution, which include steps in differentiation, steps in solving the rational equation, and computing the test values of the function.

Comment: i have a curiosity to know that how you obtained $g'(x)$ in such a simple form, I was getting as $2x^3+15x^2+35x+25=0$ and was unable to get any trivial roots.

Also I want to know that how did you solve $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{1}{x+4}=0$

Comment: [Logarithmic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation) is a good method of getting around product rule.  I will edit the steps into my answer.

Comment: Can you please also tell me that how did you solve, $\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{x+2}+\frac{1}{x+3}+\frac{1}{x+4}=0$, did you use any short method because otherwise this problem seems to be very lengthy.

Comment: I solved the rational equation by solving $2x^3+15x^2+35x+25=0$; see my comment in VladimirPutin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The function is symmetric about the line $x = -2.5$

We could write

$f(x) = ((x+2.5) + 1.5)((x+2.5)+0.5)((x+2.5)-0.5)((x+2.5) - 1.5) + 5$

Which equals

$f(x) = ((x+2.5)^2 - 1.5^2)((x+2.5)^2-0.5^2) + 5$

Now lets do the substituion $u = (x+2.5)^2$

$(u - 2.25)(u-0.25) + 5$

Which has its minimum when $u = \frac {5}{4}$

$(\frac {5}{4} - 2.25)(\frac {5}{4}-0.25) + 5 = 4$

Answer (score 0):

Continuing discussion in comments, use first derivative test.
$$
f’(x)=2x^3+15x^2+35x+25=(2x+5)(x^2+5x+5)
$$
Now the roots for the quadratic are
$x = \frac{-5+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \frac{-5-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. So to check for maximum and minimum value, check $f(-6)=120$, $f(\frac{-5+\sqrt{5}}{2})=-1$, $f(\frac{5}{2})>0$ cannot be max/min by your discussion, $f(\frac{-5-\sqrt{5}}{2})=-1$ and $f(6)=5040$. So we just take the max/min now.

Comment: But how did you solve this cubic equation, because I was not getting any trivial roots and was unable to solve cubic.

Comment: You have to guess $x=-2.5$ is a local maximum of the graph, because the graph $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)$ is symmetric about the line $x=-2.5$

Comment: Tbh I cheated, it would’ve taken a lot of time if I tried to compute by hand.

Comment: [Rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) tells you that $2x^3+15x^2+35x+25$ potentially has roots in the form $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p|25$ and $q|2$.

Comment: @VladimirPutin, how did you know that graph is symmetric about $x=-2.5$, sorry for asking too many questions, I am just a learner.

Comment: Replace $x=y+2.5$, we get $(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)=(y-1.5)(y-0.5)(y+0.5)(y+1.5)=h(y)$. Now for this new function $h(y)$, we have $h(y)=h(-y)$ (check this yourself!). I think it’s okay to ask questions, I’m also practicing by answering questions, as long as you show effort to try to understand the things.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=(x^2+5x+4)(x^2+5x+6)+5=(x^2+5x+5)^2-1+5\geq4.$$
The equality occurs for $x^2+5x+5=0,$ which happens on $[-6,6],$ which says that $4$ is a minimal value.

Now, $f(6)=5045$ and since for any $-6\leq x\leq6$ 
$$5045-f(x)=(6-x)(x+11)(x^2+5x+76)\geq0,$$ we see that $5045$ is a maximal value.

Comment: Elegant.  This was probably the intended solution.

Comment: just a small correction, f(6)=5045

Comment: @user3290550 It was typo.  I fixed. See now.

Answer (score 0):

The range will be f(X)$\in$[4,5045]

It is simple approach will be solution to quadratic equation as in article. https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/solution-of-quadratic-equation/